# Error Getting Dependencies for Matplotlib

Tags: package-management, python, dependencies, virtualenv, matplotlib

I am trying to install the python package matplotlib from source. I cannot install the package from the repository using `sudo apt-get install python-matplotlib` because I need to be able to install the package in a `virtualenv` using a `requirmenets.txt` file. When I follow the [instructions](http://matplotlib.org/1.3.1/users/installing.html) to install dependencies I get the following error:

```
vagrant@vagrant-ubuntu-trusty-64:~$ sudo apt-get build-dep python-matplotlib
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
Picking 'matplotlib' as source package instead of 'python-matplotlib'
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 python3-all-dbg : Depends: libpython3-all-dbg (= 3.4.0-0ubuntu2) but it is not going to be installed
                   Depends: python3-dbg (= 3.4.0-0ubuntu2) but it is not going to be installed
                   Depends: python3.4-dbg but it is not going to be installed
 python3-all-dev : Depends: libpython3-all-dev (= 3.4.0-0ubuntu2) but it is not going to be installed
                   Depends: python3-dev (= 3.4.0-0ubuntu2) but it is not going to be installed
                   Depends: python3.4-dev but it is not going to be installed
 python3-numpy-dbg : Depends: python3-dbg but it is not going to be installed
E: Build-dependencies for python-matplotlib could not be satisfied.
```

How do I fix the problem? I have already run `sudo apt-get update` and
`sudo apt-get upgrade` to no avail. Could I just directly install the dependencies listed in the error message (I thought that was the point of the command)? I am not even using Python 3 so not concerned about having the packages installed (though not sure why I need them either). When I try running `pip install -r requirements.txt` in the virtual environment I still get an error on installing matplotlib.

Answer (score 1):

There's a [bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/python-urllib3/+bug/1500768) in the current Ubuntu 14.04 packaging of Python.

One suggested workaround is to downgrade:

```
apt-get install -y --force-yes python3.4{,-minimal}=3.4.0-2ubuntu1.1 libpython3.4{,-minimal,-stdlib}=3.4.0-2ubuntu1.1
```

This worked in my *very* limited testing, but comments on the bug report indicate that it broke other packages.

There's also a proposed update available, which I have not tried. See comments on the bug report for details.